# Gutenberg: is is possible to get the current permalink of the post?

Tags: block-editor

I would like to get the current permalink of the post. Ideally on an "onSavePermalink" event.

Is this possible?

(For clarity - I mean in Gutenberg, in some JS for Admin Panel plugin / block)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by getting this? A common use case is trying to set post meta on save from a metabox using a second REST API/AJAX call, which is very bad practice and completely unnecessary. There is no specific "on save permalink" event though. Use the edit link under the tags to add more context to your question as the solution is not a straight forward answer and _depends_ on why you want it

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks. Problem solved. I am using: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostSlug() in a useSelect call. it gets the most recently updated slug. I want it to build a url which I show to the user in the DocumentSettings panel - the url is on another site but makes use of the slug.

Comment: can you post that as an answer instead of a comment? I can't upvote comments and you can't mark a comment as the correct answer

Comment: @TomJNowell. ok.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I am using: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostSlug() in a useSelect call. it gets the most recently updated slug. I want it to build a url which I show to the user in the DocumentSettings panel - the url is then used on another site (which access data via the Rest API) but makes use of the slug.

A large part of this seems to be about becoming familiar with the main modules and the documentation for each one. If it helps anyone else, this is [the documentation for core/editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/) which you can use to get information about the current post.